# SHAP DeepExplainer for LSTM time series data

Tags: pytorch, lstm, shap

I have a PyTorch LSTM model that takes as input a sequence of 12 time series values, and I also include 3 static features. The output is a sequence of 6 values. I want to use SHAP (SHapley Additive exPlanations) to determine which features contribute the most to the model's predictions. However, when I use the following code,
I encounter an error: `AssertionError: The model output must be a vector or a single value!`

````
import tensorflow as tf
import shap
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()

def custom_forward(lstm_input ,fc_input):
    # Pass fc_input and lstm_input to your model
    output = model_lstm(lstm_input, fc_input)
    output = output.view(-1)
    return output

batch = next(iter(dataloader_test))
lstm_input = batch['lstm_input']
fc_input = batch['fc_input']

e = shap.DeepExplainer((lstm_input, fc_input), custom_forward)
shap_values = e.shap_values((lstm_input, fc_input)) ```
````